# R ggplot Barplot doesn't start at 0, ylim and coord_cartesian don't work

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, axis

We're working on a biology project with a few different conditions to grow plants in, and we're having some difficulties with cranking out the barplot we want.
Our code

```
inzet <- matrix(
    c("control", "zout", "anaeroob", "anaeroob en zout",
    mean.c, mean.z, mean.a, mean.az, st.c, st.z, st.a, st.az,
    high.c, high.z, high.a, high.az, low.c, low.z, low.a, low.az),
    nrow=4,    
    ncol=5,       #high and low are for creating the errorbars
    byrow=FALSE
)
behandeling <- c("control", "zout", "anaeroob", "anaeroob en zout")
dimnames(inzet)=list(c(1,2,3,4),c("behandeling", "mean", "st", "high", "low"))
inzet <- as.data.frame(inzet)

ggplot(inzet, aes(x=behandeling, y=mean)) + 
      coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,40)) +  #this SHOULD fix the y-scale troubles
      geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
      geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=low, ymax=high),
            width=.2,                    # Width of the error bars
            position=position_dodge(.9))
```

gives us the following graph: 
[image]

What did we miss/overlook, that causes it to start at ±17?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add `dput(inzet)`? We don't know what the means are. But looking at your graph, your issue that you have factor variables. Matrices can only hold one dtatype, so all numbers get converted to character.

Comment: Factor seems to be the issue, thanks.
Is there a simple way to un-factorize it?

Comment: that's a FAQ: `as.numeric(as.character(x))`

Comment: Thanks a lot, have a nice day.